# Android. Pass data from activity to firefox addon

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is it able to run firefox with parameters to my addon, which will execute suitable code? Or create callback for intent.startActivity from here https://github.com/cscott/skeleton-addon-fxandroid/blob/jni/bootstrap.js

Answer (score 0):

Very cool question. I think it is very much possible. Would `Intent`s do the trick?

You can use JNI from firefox addons - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/JNI.jsm

Comment: Ok, I can openActivity, but how I pass data back from my activity to ff addon?

Comment: @umni4ek I am assuming that you understand the android api as you have an app already from the sounds of it. You would have to have your activity send an intent to firefox, and you would have to set up firefox to listen to those intents.

Comment: how to get firefox to listen intents?

Comment: You would write the code with JNI.jsm do you know the Android API?

Comment: I know Android API. Is there some way to make analogue of startActivityForResult from firefox addon?

Comment: @umni4ek absolutely, just follow that guid on jni.jsm here is another example of me doing some jni work - https://gist.github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=jni+%40noitidart